# Create a query that returns the expiration date of a product

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2016

I'm trying to create an inventory system to track the products a certain person owns.

I have 2 tables. In the first one I have information about the person and the last time she received a certain product. The same person can receive more than one product. In the other table, I have information about every available product, and there I know that product 1 (for example) expirates after 1 year, and so on

Table1:

| Person ID | ProductID | Receive date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 20-05-2020 |

Table2:

| ProductID | Lifespan |
| --- | --- |
| A | 2 |
| B | 1 |

I  wanted to create a query where I could join both tables, so that I knew that the certain product that a certain person owns has it's expiration date on a certain day.
I used this code (I did it in Design View, as I am not an expert in SQL):

```
SELECT [Table1].[PersonID], [Table1].[ProductID], [Table1].[Receive Date], [Table2].[Lifespan]
FROM [Table2] INNER JOIN [Table1] ON [Table2].ProductID = [Table1].[ProductID];
```

The problem is that, as I create the query, the results are not correct. I'm receiving something like:

| Person ID | Product | Receive date | Lifespan | Expiration Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A |  |  |  |
| 1 | A |  |  |  |
| 1 | A |  |  |  |
| 2 | A |  |  |  |
| 2 | A |  |  |  |
| 2 | A |  |  |  |

He is only returning the same product and not the products received. Also I don't know how to return the expiration date in the date format (the receive date is in date format and the lifespan field is just a short number format)

Hope somebody can help me! Thank you very much

Comment: Edit question to show sample data as well as attempted SQL.

Comment: Why is there no data in [Receive date] field? Can't calculate expiration without it. Would use DateAdd() function to calculate expiration. Strongly advise not to use spaces nor punctuation/special characters in naming convention. Table names could be more informative. Your query lacks a JOIN clause which is why query shows duplicate rows.

Comment: @June7 I had to change my data to post here as my document is in another language. In reality my tables have real names. I'll take the note about the Fields name, thank you! About the [Receive date], it's a date (when I transferred the data to the post I forgot about that part)

Comment: @June7 can you please explain where can I add the JOIN clause in the code?

Comment: Use Access query builder. Click ProductID field in one table and drag to ProductID field in other table. This will create link. Switch to SQLView to see SQL statement.

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much! Regarding the expiration date, I tried using the DateAdd() but as I'm using data from fields (in the number and date the information comes from the table), it's giving me an error. The expression is: 
Expr1: DateAdd("yyyy";[Table2].[Lifespan];[Table1].[Receive Date])
Can it be because I'm not doing it right?

Comment: And what error? With both tables in the query, expression should work. Not necessary to include the table names in this case but shouldn't hurt.

Comment: @June7 when I run the query it just appears #error in every cell

Comment: I tested query with INNER JOIN and DateAdd expression and works for me. Only difference is comma instead of semi-colon. Edit question to show your revised SQL statement.

Comment: Mine doesn't work and I can't understand why, already tried to change everything and still it just says #Error when I run the query. I changed my lifespan to days instead of years and I'm trying with DateAdd("d",[Lifespan],[Receive Date]), but it just doesn't work

Comment: Can't replicate so can't offer solution. Might want to post to a forum that allows attaching files and provide db for analysis.